# how to set a modeline in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

E.g., for Vim, I can add such a modeline in my Python file:

```
# vim: tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```

This would overwrite the default formatting (tab space, indent settings, etc) for this file.

Is there some similar modeline for PyCharm? I want to put some header comment in my file about formatting options so that this will be applied to this file (and only this file).

This is something different than to have global formatting settings. [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org) is great for this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't be able to get the kind of leverage you get with Vim in PyCharm just by using PyCharm's default style options, and so I suggest you download and install the [Vim plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164). Here's where the Style options are:

[image]

For Vim, you can set your options in `~/.ideavimrc`.

Comment: I just want to set a modeline. I don't want anything Vim related. That was just an example. Also, I want the modeline in the file itself (that is what a modeline is), not in another file. I can easily get that via an external file e.g. via EditorConfig.

Answer (score 0):

None of the Jetbrains products currently support settings changes defined within the file they affect. You might try to look into writing a plugin to accomplish what you want.